# Laravel - how to pass parameter to action link from js

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to dynamically build an action link for adding items to a database in Laravel. The problem is that I need to pass a parameter with category_id, which I only get after selecting the category in html select element.

I thought about using the even onChange() on select element, and then building up the link in js function, and finally setting it to "a" element with the help of js selector. However this approach doesn't work.

```
var link = "{{ action('ItemController@create', [ 'id' =>"+selectedId.value+"]) }}"; 
document.getElementById("AddItemLink").href = link;
```

Is producing: http://localhost:8000/item/create/+selectedId.value+

What I need to get is: http://localhost:8000/item/create/8

If I do console.log(selectedId.value), the output is correct - 8.

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that,

```
var link = "/item/create/"+ selectedId.value;

document.getElementById("AddItemLink").href = link;
```